# How to find the corresponding React prop for html Elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

In React you don't write `<div class='container'></div>` but you write `<div className='container'></div>`

Where are all this props listed?
For a `<textarea>`, I want to add `withspellcheck={false}` but I can not find the correct name of the prop. Do you have Ideas where these prop configurations are saved in the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: [React: DOM Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) specifically [All Supported HTML Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes) (appears to be `spellCheck` for your specific example)

Comment: Thanks. somehow i was stucked with ``withspellcheck`. Your answer is the accepted answer.